# csrf_exempt decorator not exempting

Tags: php, django, wordpress, curl, csrf-protection

I have a wordpress site (coded with PHP) that I am using to post data to a django view. I post with this code

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://mydjangosite.com/blah/blah2/');
```

The function the url above goes to is using the `@csrf_exempt` decorator because I want to allow a cross-site post in this instance

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
@api_wrapper
def add_referral_api(request, status_slug):
```

However, I still receive this error in my logs

```
[03/Feb/2017 18:17:48] WARNING [django.request:177] Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):
```

How can I allow such cross-site posting between trusted sites?

**EDIT**
My Middleware Classes are as such. Note that this site uses a ssl certificate, for what it's worth, and I suspect that the extra security is causing the `csrf_exemption` decorator to not work as I would hope. Even still, I'd like to somehow be able to say that this one site (my WP site) is okay to receive post data from.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This middleware is for ensuring that all pages use https
    #'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'common.middleware.XsSharing',
    'impersonate.middleware.ImpersonateMiddleware',
    'referrals.middleware.ReferralMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: What does "api_wrapper" do? Are you certain this view is the one being hit?

Comment: Yes. What it does is take the information posted and adds records to the database.

Comment: Do you have by any chance the `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` setting set to `True`?

Comment: I thought of that, too, but no it is not.

Comment: Can you list your middlewares?

Comment: Yes. Please see my question edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134837/discussion-between-raphael-gomes-and-matt-cremeens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with Matt, we discovered the culprit to be the `@api_wrapper` decorator (so, my initial intuition was right), as it was calling the `@ensure_csrf_token` decorator, rendering the `@csrf_exempt` useless. The PHP call gave a `Bad Request (400)`, but that's out of the scope of this question.